# Issue with bat script checking cellular connection status and then displaying IP if connected or displaying not connected if not on cellular

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, ip

I have been tinkering with this for a while and I am unable to make this fully work in a script. If I run commands separately they work as expected...any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
    cls
    @echo off

    set celValue=

    for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in ('netsh mbn show connection interface^="Cellular"^| findstr 
    "Interface"') do set celValue=%%a

    if "%celValue%"=="Connected" (for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%i in ('netsh interface ip show config 
    name^="Cellular"^| findstr "IP Address"') do echo Cellular IP: %%i) else (echo Cellular not 
    connected)
    
    pause
```

Comment: why the whitespace between `^ |` at the first `findstr` and why no pipe in second `findstr` it should be `^|`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I know I have written the way you mentioned...not sure why my bat file didn't save that. I must've been tinkering with it and forgot to add those and fix those whitespaces...but I do know I have tested it with the proper ^| and also had it in the second findstr and I still get issues. Do you see anything else that I am missing or perhaps messed up? Thank you! I edited the original post to reflect your changes.

Comment: have you confirmed the value of `%celValue%` returned is `Connected` and not `connected` - `IF` conditonal checks are case sensitive unless the `/I` switch is used

Comment: Thank you I will test this later today and let you know! Thanks!

Comment: I decided to use the /I switch...thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to test this as I have no broadband connections on this device. So you'd need to do the testing for us. So besides the esacpaing issues shown in a comment, your parenthesized code blocks had the incorrect formatting.

```
cls
@echo off
set celValue=

for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%a in ('netsh mbn show connection interface^="Cellular" ^| findstr /I "Interface"') do set celValue=%%a
    if "%celValue%"=="Connected" (
        for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %%i in ('netsh interface ip show config name^="Cellular" ^| findstr /I "IP Address"') do (
            echo Cellular IP: %%i
   )
  ) else (
    echo Cellular not connected
 )
pause
```